# Binding Tab Item to TabControl Dynamically in MVVM Format

Tags: mvvm, richtextbox, tabcontrol, tabitem

How to Bind Tab Items to the TabControl Dynamically and Display a RichTextBox in each tab and i want to append some data to the RichTextBox in MVVM Format.

Comment: WPF or UWP or Xamarin Forms?

Answer (score 1):

Well... here is some generalized code which you needed. If you have any sppecific requirement let me know ...

XAML....

```
<Window x:Class="wpfApplication.Views.Test"
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GateApplication.Views"
     xmlns:c="clr-namespace:wpfApplication.Commands"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:wpfApplication.ViewModels"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
     Title ="Test" Height="550" Width="825">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:TestVM></vm:TestVM>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
<TabControl Width="450" Margin="2,2,2,2" ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}">
                <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}"></TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                    <RichTextBox>
                        <FlowDocument>
                            <Paragraph>
                                <Run Text="{Binding Content}"></Run>
                            </Paragraph>
                        </FlowDocument>
                        </RichTextBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and View Model is...

```
public class TestVM : ViewModelBase
    {       
        public TestVM()
        {       

            Tabs = new ObservableCollection<TabItem>();
            Tabs.Add(new TabItem { Header = "One", Content = "One's content" });
            Tabs.Add(new TabItem { Header = "Two", Content = "Two's content" });
        }
        public sealed class TabItem
        {
            public string Header { get; set; }
            public string Content { get; set; }
        }
    }
```